# R function transform a vector to columns

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to add columns to a data.frame with known vector's values?

I have a dataframe "Now"

```
Now<-data.frame(1:4)
Vect<-c(A,B,C)
Vect_name<-c("x1","x2","x3")
```

I want a dataframe result like this:

```
Result<-data.frame(c(1:4),"A","B","C")
colnames(Result)<-Vect_name
```

and I want the code is also applicable when the length of "Vect" and "Vect_name" is variable.
I mean Vect could be c(A,B,C,D...) and Vect_name could be c("x1","x2","x3","x4"...).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `base R` by assigning the `list` of 'Vect' (convert to a `list`) to the column names in 'Vect_name'

```
Now[Vect_name]  <- as.list(Vect)
```

Or if we don't want to change the original object, use `cbind`

```
Now1 <- cbind(Now, t(setNames(Vect, Vect_name)))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, create a named `list` column and then use `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Now %>% 
    mutate(col = list(as.list(set_names(Vect, Vect_name)))) %>% 
    unnest_wider(col)
```

#### data

```
Vect <- c("A", "B", "C")
```